# How to get sum of column based on two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame (`df`) with 5 columns: `Area.Name`, `Age`, `Total`, `Rural` and `Urban`. I need to get sum total for `Total` based on `Area.Name` and then into two categories based on `Age`: 0-2 and 3-4.

```
df <- 
structure(list(Area.Name = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("District - Central (06)", "District - East (04)", 
"District - New Delhi (05)", "District - North (02)", "District - North East (03)", 
"District - North West (01)", "District - South (09)", "District - South West (08)", 
"District - West (07)", "NCT OF DELHI (07)"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Total = c(56131L, 
    58644L, 63835L, 63859L, 64945L, 24556L, 27076L, 27234L, 27604L, 
    27725L, 30780L), Rural = c(3589L, 3757L, 4200L, 4102L, 4223L, 
    52L, 56L, 61L, 47L, 67L, 53L), Urban = c(52542L, 54887L, 
    59635L, 59757L, 60722L, 24504L, 27020L, 27173L, 27557L, 27658L, 
    30727L)), .Names = c("Area.Name", "Age", "Total", "Rural", 
"Urban"), row.names = c(102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 405L, 406L, 
407L, 408L, 409L, 410L), class = "data.frame")
```

My expected output is:

```
Area.Name                    Age Total   
District - North West (01)   0-2 178610  
District - North West (01)   3-4 128804  
District - East (04)         0-2 78866
District - East (04)         3-4 55329
```

I tried using `dplyr` package but I am not so well versed with this, so kind of stuck here:

```
df %>% group_by(Area.Name) %>% summarize(Age = Age[0],Tot = sum(Total))
```

The problem is that here for `Age` I am not able to give a range.

Comment: I was trying `df %>% group_by(Area.Name) %>% summarize(Age = Age[0],Tot = sum(Total))` But the problem is that here for Age I am not able to give a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way where I `cut()` the `Age` inline with the `group_by` function:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Area.Name, Age = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 2, 4, +Inf), 
                                labels = c("0-2", "3-4", "4+"), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Total))

#                    Area.Name    Age  Total
#                       <fctr> <fctr>  <int>
# 1       District - East (04)    0-2  78866
# 2       District - East (04)    3-4  55329
# 3       District - East (04)     4+  30780
# 4 District - North West (01)    0-2 178610
# 5 District - North West (01)    3-4 128804
```

To get only the desired groups, you can add `%>% filter(Age %in% c("0-2", "3-4"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method in base R using `cut` and `aggregate`:

```
df$ageCat <- cut(df$Age, breaks=c(0, 2, max(df$Age)), include.lowest = T)
aggregate(Total~Area.Name+ageCat, data=df, sum)
                   Area.Name ageCat  Total
1       District - East (04)  [0,2]  78866
2 District - North West (01)  [0,2] 178610
3       District - East (04)  (2,5]  86109
4 District - North West (01)  (2,5] 128804
```

`cut` breaks the Age variable into the desired categories. The data.frame is then aggregated over the desired variables.

Comment: For group building you can also use `.bincode` like `df$group <- .bincode(df$Age, c(0, 2, 4), include.lowest = T)`